# Angular JS/Karma Unit Testing with Angular UI-Router

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, gruntjs, angular-ui, karma-runner

I'm working on an Angular app that uses Angular UI-Router for routing and maintaining state. I am having a hard time getting my unit test to even compile. It seems that no matter what I do, I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: State '' is not navigable
```

I have the following states set up in my app, as well as the following redirects:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

var paramList = '?beds&lat&lon&zoom';

$urlRouterProvider
    .when('', '/')
    .when('/', '/search')
    .when('/search', '/search/list')
    .otherwise('');

$stateProvider
    .state('search', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/search',
        templateUrl: 'views/search.html',
        controller: 'SearchCtrl'
     })
        .state('search.list', {
            url: '/list' + paramList,
            templateUrl: 'views/search-list.html'
         })
        .state('search.map', {
            url: '/map' + paramList,
            templateUrl: 'views/search-map.html'
        })
    .state('search.listing', {
        url: '/listing/:id' + paramList,
        templateUrl: 'views/search-listing.html'
    })
    .state('favorites', {
        url: '/favorites',
        templateUrl: 'views/favorites.html'
    })
});
```

I've eaten up an entire day trying to get a single test to work, but no matter what approach I take, I always end up at this same error. I have an e2e test running just fine.

Answer (score 1):

ui-router adds an internal state for `''` automatically, so that is the error you are getting. I recommend adding a `'/'` url for a base state and change the 'otherwise' invocation to redirect to '/' instead of ''. The internal `''` state is being attempted because of your `.otherwise('')` call. So perhaps try this:

```
$urlRouterProvider
.when('/', '/search')
.when('/search', '/search/list')
.otherwise('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I would say it looks like the $stateProvider is telling you you need to put an empty state in there. Add this to the list of states.

```
state( '', { ... } )
```

Comment: I tried this, and the error I get now is `Uncaught Error: State ''' is already defined from app`.